# Using Linearity, how can I find Vo in this circuit? (not homework)

Tags: linear

I am making the assumption that Vo is 1V.  Moving right-to-left through the circuit, I want to use that assumption to find Vs.  Then, the ratio of the real Vs to my found Vs will be the same ratio from the real Vo to my assumed Vo = 1V.  I am having trouble figuring out what to do next though.  Any tips?  My markings are in blue on the attached picture.

[image]

Possible next step:  KCL @ the top node between the 2k and 4k resistors (calling this V3).... nodal analysis:

1 - V_3 = 8V, V_3 = -7V (???)

Comment: \$1/4k = 4mA\$???!!!

Comment: sorry!  ha...  0.25mA

Comment: So 2k*0.25 = 0.5V across the 2k ohm resistor;  so 1 - V3 = 0.5, so V3 = 0.5 V

Comment: Yes. voltage across 2k resistor is 0.5V. What is V3?

Comment: V_3 = 0.5V also because V0 is assumed to be 1V, right?  But, I'm stuck here; I don't know what to do next..

Comment: If V3 denotes the voltage across 6k resistor, then you are wrong. V3 is not 0.5V. Because Vo is not a source.

Comment: But if Vo is 1V, and the voltage across the 2k resistor is 0.5, would V3 - Vo = voltage across 2k = 0.5, so V3 - 1 = 0.5, making V3 1.5V?

Comment: now that makes sense. :)

Comment: Okay, so what next?

Comment: use KCL and KVL equations to find voltage across 8k resistor and then solve for Vs.

Comment: So I renamed the nodes... the bottom left is V1, top left V2, then V3, and V4, with V4 = 1.5V.  Now, to do KCL (nodal analysis) I need three equations because I have three unknowns (V1,V2,V3), but how I was only able to build two equations:  2V_3 - 2V_2 + V_3 - V_1 + 2V_3 - 3 = 0, and 3V_1 - 3V_3 + 2V_1 - 3 + 8V_1 - V2 = 0 ----- Simplified: -v_1 -2V_2 + 5v_3 = 3, and 13v_1 - V_2 - 3V_3 = 3

Comment: You have four nodes. The voltage at 1st node V1=0. V2, V3 and V4 are unknowns. Voltage difference between third and fourth node is 1.5. ie, V4 = V3+1.5. So now you have two unknowns to solve V2 and V3. Now 2 equations are enough to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Working resistance values from right to left to simplify the circuit.

Series R7 and R8 gives 6k

This value, in parallel with R6, this gives 3k

This value, in series with R5, gives 6k

This value in parallel with R4, gives 4k

This value,in series with R2, gives 8k

This value , in parallel with R3, gives 4k (which is equal to R1) so the voltage at this node (after R1) = 10V

R4,5,6,7 and 8 produce an effective 4k resistance so the voltage at the second node  (after R2) must be be half that value i.e. 10 * 0.5 = 5V.

The voltage across R5 is 5/2V (as R6 // (R7 and R8) = 3K)

So the voltage across R7 and R8 must also  be 5/2V  (= 5 - 5/2).

So Vo = R8/(R7 + R8) * 5/2 =  4/6 * 5/2 = 20/12 or **5/3V**

Answer (score 1):

[image: Diagram]

$$\newcommand\mAmp{\;\text{mA}} \newcommand\Volt{\;\text{V}} \newcommand\kOhm{\;\text{k}\Omega} \newcommand\Vsrc{V_{\text{S}}} \newcommand\Vsrcf{V_{\text{S}_f}}$$

For this circuit I work with current when I find series circuits and voltages with parallel circuits.

I use equations to indicate the relationship (parallel, series) between components.  My convention is \$\parallel\$ for parallel relationships, and \$\nparallel\$ for series relationships--for lack of a better alternative.

So, starting with \$V_0 = 1\Volt\$

- You found \$I_8 = \frac{V_0}{R_8} = \frac{1 \Volt}{4 \kOhm} = 0.25 \mAmp\$
- Which is the same current through \$R_7\$ => \$I_7 = I_8 = 0.25 \mAmp\$
- Now we have a parallel circuit with \$R_6 \parallel (R_7, R_8)\$, and \$V_6 = V_{7,8}\$ so I need \$V_{7,8}\$

\begin{align}
V_{7,8} &= V_7 + V_8 = (R_7 + R_8) \cdot I_8 = (6 \kOhm)(0.25 \mAmp)=1.5 \Volt \\
V_6 &= V_{7,8} = 1.5 \Volt
\end{align}

- \$R_5\$ is in series with \$(R_6, R_7, R_8)\$, so back to current.  \$I_5 = I_6 + I_7\$ using KCL.  Rinse and repeat.

Here's the rest.

\begin{align}
I_5 &= I_6 + I_7 = \frac{V_6}{R_6} + I_7 = \frac{1.5 \Volt}{6 \kOhm} + 0.25 \mAmp = 0.5 \mAmp \\
R_4 &\parallel (R_5, R_6) \implies V_4 = V_{5,6} \\
V_4 &= V_{5,6} = V_5 + V_{7,8} = R_5I_5 + V_{7,8} = (3 \kOhm)(0.5 \mAmp) + 1.5 \Volt = 3 \Volt \\
R_3 &\nparallel (R_4, R_5, R_6, R_7, R_8) \implies I_3 = I_4 + I_6 + I_7 \;\text{using KCL} \\
I_3 &= \frac{V_4}{R_4} + I_6 + I_7 = \frac{3 \Volt}{12 \kOhm} + 0.25 \mAmp + 0.25 \mAmp = 0.75 \mAmp \\
R_2 &\parallel (R_3, R_4, \dots) \implies V_2 = V_{2,3,4,5,6,7,8} \\
V_2 &= V_3 + V_4 = R_3I_3 + V_4 = (4 \kOhm)(0.75 \mAmp) + 3 \Volt = 6 \Volt \\
R_1 &\nparallel (R_2, R_3, \dots) \implies I_1 = I_2 + I_3 \\
I_1 &= \frac{V_2}{R_2} + I_3 = \frac{6 \Volt}{8 \kOhm} + 0.75 \mAmp = 1.5 \mAmp \\
\Vsrc &\parallel (R_1, R_2) \implies \Vsrc = V_1 + V_2 \\
\Vsrc &= R_1I_1 + V_2 = (4 \kOhm)(1.5 \mAmp) + 6 \Volt = 12 \Volt
\end{align}

Given \$\Vsrcf = 20 \Volt\$,

\begin{align}
V_{0_f} &= \displaystyle{\frac{\Vsrcf}{\Vsrc}} \cdot V_0 = \frac{20 \Volt}{12 \Volt} \cdot 1 \Volt = \frac{5}{3} \Volt
\end{align}

It's a the same strategy from right-to-left as from left-to-right.  You just have the extra step of your linearity equation.

Some may wonder, "Why go through this effort?"  If you know your desired output voltage, you can use this to find the supply voltage.  In this case you want a \$12 \Volt\$ supply voltage, but only have a \$20 \Volt\$, and with linearity can compute how that will affect your output voltage without working left-to-right.